# Round the corners of a textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I would like to round the corners of a textbox. Up to this point I got there because I found online a class made by someone who rounded the corners of a textbox. But the point is, I don't know how to make it bigger, in fact it remains very small.

I tried to enlarge it with this: `text.Size = new Size(100, 100);`but the round textbox continues to remain small. Why do you think? how could i enlarge it?

[image: In this image we see little since it is white]

*Round TextBox class:*

```
class round : TextBox
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
        (
            int nLeftRect, // X-coordinate of upper-left corner or padding at start
            int nTopRect,// Y-coordinate of upper-left corner or padding at the top of the textbox
            int nRightRect, // X-coordinate of lower-right corner or Width of the object
            int nBottomRect,// Y-coordinate of lower-right corner or Height of the object
                            //RADIUS, how round do you want it to be?
            int nheightRect, //height of ellipse 
            int nweightRect //width of ellipse
        );
        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            base.OnCreateControl();
            this.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(2, 3, this.Width, this.Height, 15, 15)); //play with these values till you are happy
        }
    }
```

*As I put it in the form*

```
round text = new round();
        this.Controls.Add(text);
        text.Location = new Point(114, 132);
        text.Size = new Size(100, 100);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a textbox with rounded corner in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613713/how-to-make-a-textbox-with-rounded-corner-in-c) and [Textbox with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579488/textbox-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: Take a look at [Krypton Suite of .NET WinForms Controls](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton)

Comment: Are you sure you need that?? (I would embed a TextBox in a rounded Panel)

Comment: @Olivier Rogier no, he doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Olivier Rogier I downloaded the zip. For example, how to implement KryptonTextBox Examples in my project?